# azure ad sign in redirect loop

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I am developing an internal app for company use, using the template from vs2017 which has azure AD sign in enabled.

the sign in works fine locally - however when deploying to an azure app service - I can get to the signin page for azure ad - but when i enter my credentials - it just hits a redirect loop and eventually errors.

Does anyone have any ideas how to stop this from happening ?

Code from Startup.cs:

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication();

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientSecret"],
            Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
            CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"],
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Thanks

Samuel.

Comment: Do you have login.microsoftonline.com as a trusted site in your browser, and your web site not as a trusted site (or vice-versa)? I have experienced exactly that behavior because of this trusted/not-trusted mix.

Comment: Did you config the **Authentication/Authorization** when you deploy the app to Azure? If yes, please remove it since you have config the authentication in the code. And would you mind sharing the detailed error you got?

Comment: @FeiXue this worked for me. Is there information how the config would look that takes advantage of Authentication/Authorization settings?

Comment: Did you add the URL of your deployed site in the "Reply URLs" collection in the Azure portal for the your application registration?